# Use a int in entire code

Tags: c#, scope

I am attempting to make a basic timer but I am having trouble accessing a variable.

```
public void Mins_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mintues = Convert.ToInt32(Mins.Text);
}

public void Seconds_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var second = Convert.ToInt32(Seconds.Text);
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timeLeft = (second+456);
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are running into? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Please be more precise. What is your code supposed to do? What's not working?

Comment: You should use Int.TryParse, since both of your TextChanged methods will throw an exception if you enter a non-number, the field is empty, or the value is < int.MaxValue or > int.MaxValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use global variable. Declare variable outside from function.
Example

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int minutes;
    int second;
    public void Mins_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Mins.Text);
    }

    public void Seconds_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        second = Convert.ToInt32(Seconds.Text);
    }
}
```